# Como deixar a minha query dinâmica usinda hibernate (Spring Boot)?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, spring-jpa

Olá

Estou tentando deixa a minha query dinâmica da seguinte forma a baixo:

```
@Query("SELECT T.NR_EVENT FROM TB_TIMELINE AS T WHERE T.NR_PENUMPER = :customerCode")
public List<TB_TIMELINE> getTimelineRecordsByClient(@Param("customerCode") String customerCode);
```

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

`Hibernate: SELECT T.* FROM MRC_TIMELINE.TB_TIMELINE AS T WHERE T.NR_PENUMPER = ?`

Alguem sabe como me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Você está retornando uma lista de `TB_TIMELINE`, porém, quando você faz `SELECT T.NR_EVENT ...`, você não está selecionando uma `TB_TIMELINE`, você está selecionando um `NR_EVENT` (que é um campo da entidade).
Desse jeito, o Spring Data não consegue construir o objeto para retorná-lo, justamente pelo fato de que o resultado da sua query é uma lista de `NR_EVENT`, não uma lista de `TB_TIMELINE`.

Observo três soluções possíveis:

**A primeira** é alterar seu JPQL para:

```
SELECT T FROM TB_TIMELINE AS T WHERE T.NR_PENUMPER = :customerCode
```

Dessa forma, o Spring Data é capaz de criar seu objeto (tenha em mente que isso retornará todos os atributos do banco de dados, descartando apenas objetos filhos que tenham `FetchType.LAZY`, que é o padrão para objetos aninhados)

---

**A segunda** é criar um construtor em sua classe `TB_TIMELINE` que receba um `NR_EVENT` e utilizá-lo para instanciar um novo objeto em sua query (visto que é um JPQL, isso é suportado, veja o exemplo abaixo)

**TB_TIMELINE.java**

```
public class TB_TIMELINE {
    
    private Integer NR_EVENT; // estou supondo que o tipo de NR_EVENT é Integer
    
    // desconheço os outros atributos
    
    // este é o construtor de que estou falando
    public TB_TIMELINE(Integer NR_EVENT) {
        this.NR_EVENT = NR_EVENT;
    }
    
    // mantenha o construtor default, pois é ele útil
    public TB_TIMELINE() {
    }
    
}
```

Sua query ficaria assim (sim, `new ...`. JPQL tem este suporte)

```
SELECT new seu.pacote.TB_TIMELINE(T.NR_EVENT) FROM TB_TIMELINE AS T WHERE T.NR_PENUMPER = :customerCode
```

*Obs: não se esqueça de colocar o pacote na criação da instância, como no exemplo acima.*

Assim, seria retornada uma `List` de `TB_TIMELINE` com o atributo `NR_EVENT` preenchido e com todos os outros campos nulos

---

**A terceira** é alterar o tipo de retorno do seu método para uma `List` do tipo do campo `NR_EVENT`, por exemplo:

```
@Query("SELECT T.NR_EVENT FROM TB_TIMELINE AS T WHERE T.NR_PENUMPER = :customerCode")
public List<Integer> getTimelineRecordsByClient(@Param("customerCode") String customerCode);
```

Neste caso, será retornado uma lista com os números.